# Is this Chinese sentence grammatical? I'm unsure about a few words and phrases

Tags: translation, grammar

I've been trying to translate this sentence but there are a few points I'm puzzled on:

市场调查部就最近为针对Quest公司在市场策略上对'以客户为主以雇员为本'所作出的调整而拟定的方案发表了分内整和外扩的两个方面的建议，其目的为促使本公司在相应策略上能够与时并进，从而得到市场竞争力的提升.

This is the best I've been able to translate myself:
The market research department, regarding Quest Company's newest market strategy, the produced 'Customer First and Employee-Based,' adjusted and drafted plan, has issued a double-aspect suggestion of [.....] and outward expansion, the aim of which is to impel the company's coordinating strategy to keep up with the times, and as a result can attain a rise in market competitiveness.

Four questions I have on certain words and phrases in the original Chinese:

1. What does '就' mean here?
2. What does '为针对' mean?
3. What does '分内整' mean?  (Something about doing one's part?)
4. What does '其目的为促使本公司在相应策略上能够与时并进' mean?

Thank you very much for your help, if you are able to help me.
--Rachel

Comment: 市场调查部`subject` 就`for` (最近为针对Quest公司在市场策略上对'以客户为主以雇员为本'所作出的调整而拟定的方案) `some plan` 发表了`verb` 分`short for 分为, it means correspondingly` (内整和外扩的) (两个方面的) 建议`object`，其目的`subject` 为`verb` (促使本公司在相应策略上能够与时并进)`sentence as object`，从而得到市场竞争力的提升.

Comment: Such a sentence has many nested syntactic structures. Even for a native speaker, without careful syntactic analyses, he/she can't completely understand it. Anyway I don't think it's a good style in writing. Totally unnatural.

Answer (score 2):

Okay .... [takes a deep breath]

就 in regard to the

BLANK1

方案 plan,

市场调查部 the Marketing Survey Department

发表了 presented their

BLANK2

建议， suggestions;

其目的为  the goal of their suggestions is

促使 to ensure that

本公司 THE COMPANY,

在相应策略上, as far as the relevant strategies are concerned

能够 is able to

与时并进， keep pace with the times

从而 and thus

提升 市场上的竞争力 increase their competitiveness in the market

BLANK 1 describes a plan which was

最近 recently

拟定 formulated

为 in order to

针对 take account of

所作出的调整 the adjustments made

在市场策略上 to marketing strategies

of/by Quest公司,

对' specificially --

以客户为主 customers as the key

以雇员为本' employees as the base,

的方案 THAT plan.

BLANK 2 describes how the suggestion includes

分 dividing the plan into

两个方面的 two parts:

内整 internal consolidation

和 and

外扩 external expansion

In answer to the other parts of the question:

> Is the sentence grammatical?

- This sentence should be taken outside and shot.

> What does 就 mean here?

- Acc. to the [教育部國語辭典](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/newDict/dict.sh?cond=%B4N&pieceLen=50&fld=1&cat=&ukey=673120434&serial=1&recNo=61&op=f&imgFont=1) 就 here is a preposition (coverb) that means: 依照。 如：「就事論事」、「就原來的規畫加以調整。」 I often translate as in regard to; this is an old habit, but surely other translations (based on?) would work too.

> What does 為針對 mean here?

- 為 is a coverb that means in order to, 針對 is verbish creature that means to direct toward, to take into consideration. 國語辭典 gives a nice example: 「為了節省時間，請大家儘量針對問題來討論。」

> What does '分内整' mean?

- You've divided it wrong, its 分 | 内整 和 外扩 (两个方面)

> What does '其目的为促使本公司在相应策略上能够与时并进' mean?

- hopefully looking at the literal translation above will help answer

Answer (score 1):

1: I’d read the 就 as a filler, because I’ve seen it written many times, also in texts with political or economic background.
It could also imply that what happens in this sentence is a consequence of what has been mentioned earlier in the text.

2: I read 为 and 针对 as separate words, but 为 and 而 belonging together: To get a certain result, you take certain measures. You could read the 为 as 为了, “in order to”, if that makes it clear.

3: You should read 发表了 分 内整 和 外扩 的两个方面 的建议: [the proposition] expressed suggestions concerning the separation of the two aspects of keeping the company in order internally, and expanding externally.

4: 其目的为促使本公司在相应策略上能够与时并进: (simplified) translation: ...its goal being to urge this company to strategically keep up with the times.

Please note: This Chinese sentence should not be translated into one English sentence.
Please also note that neither Chinese nor English are my native language.

Answer (score 1):

Yaks. The original Chinese doesn't sound like Chinese at all. It seems to be English that has machine translated into Chinese. It is verbose, obtuse and almost incomprehensible.

Chinese - as it had been used for thousands of years - has very little grammar. "Modern Chinese" was introduced during the 5.4 Movement, which is more or less a slimmed-downed version of English grammar imposed on Chinese. Jin Yong's wuxia novels is quite close to what might be called "classical Chinese."

To answer your specific questions:

1. What does '就' mean here?
   As far as I can tell, it means "for."
2. What does '为针对' mean?
   This should be read together with '就'. The four characters mean "specifically for." However '就' is totally redundant and useless here.
3. What does '分内整' mean? (Something about doing one's part?)
   分 - divided into
   内 - internal
   整 - 整理,organize

So taken together, "divided into internal (re)organization"

4. What does '其目的为促使本公司在相应策略上能够与时并进' mean?
   translation: the purpose is to promote this company's corresponding policies can keep up with the times.

But again, very poorly written.

Hope this helps.